# How to convert date format from yyyy-mm-dd to yymmdd base on python Robot Framework

Tags: python, date, robotframework, date-conversion

How to convert date format from **yyyy-mm-dd** to date **yymmdd** base on python **Robot Framework**

I tried below Keyword in RobotFramework

```
${StartDate}=   Convert Date    2022-09-29    result_format=**%yy%MM%dd**
```

But I am getting 20220929 **yyyymmdd**

Expected Output from above example ==> 220929 **yymmdd**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: one letter must be enough actually - ``%y%m%d``. And note that big M is for minutes, not month.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as below:

```
${StartDate}=   Convert Date    2022-09-29    result_format=%y%m%d
```

This will give your expected output 220929 in yymmdd format